# Updating MS SQL Server from 10.50.1600 to 10.50.1617

Tags: updates, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I update my MS **SQL Server** from the version **10.50.1600** to **10.50.1617**?

I have downloaded the KB from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26304 but i am still not updated to the version i wanted.

Could anyone lend some help?

Comment: Why did you tag this with "MySQL"?

Comment: i have no idea... because it is related i guess... is it not?

Comment: MySQL is a entirely different program and Microsoft's SQL.  You should hover over it and read the tag. :)

Comment: ah.. ok... i can remove that correct?  
but back to the topic , can help me regarding the update?

Comment: I edited for ya. ;)  And yes I'm creating an answer right now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of SQLServer version numbers: http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/ .

To get to 10.50.1617, install update MS11-049 after installing the 10.50.1600 (2008R2 RTM) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2494088

Comment: hmm.. bro , i did try installing that kb.... :(

Comment: so you have already installed "SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM" and confirmed that it is at 10.50.1600, before attempting to install MS11-49? What makes you think you have a problem that this will fix?